# Skip test on android on specific task of Azure pipeline

Tags: android, gradle, azure-pipelines, gradle-android-test-plugi

I have an Android library project with two Unit test, and those tasks defined in the Gradle:

```
task("cleanProject", dependsOn: "clean", group: "myGroup")

task("generateAAR", dependsOn: "assembleRelease", group: "myGroup")

task("copyAAR", type: Copy, group: "myGroup") {
    from "${project.rootDir}/project/build/outputs/aar"
    into "${project.rootDir}/mydir/aar"
}
```

and I tried to use Azure pipelines by adding the following .yml:

```
    - task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    tasks: 'cleanProject'
  displayName: Clean Project

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    tasks: 'testReleaseUnitTest'
  displayName: Release Unit Test

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    tasks: 'generateAAR'
  displayName: Generate AAR Lib

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    tasks: 'copyAAR'
  displayName: Copy AAR Lib
```

It works nicely, but I noticed that the test are performed also on generateAAR and copyAAR tasks, resulting in 6 total test passed. Is there a way to exclude the tests from a specific task or pipeline?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to exclude the tests from a specific task or pipeline?

Azure devops service itself doesn't have the option to exclude tests from one task.(test level) Instead it supports disabling/skipping task in pipeline.(task level)

Check gradle's [skipping the tests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:skipping_java_tests) and [skipping the tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:skipping_tasks), I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but maybe somebody find my answer useful, because there is a way to do it, at least it works for us in the project.
Gradle Task for azure has an "options" argument, see the official docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops

[image]

This means that your final solution will look sth like this:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    tasks: 'generateAAR'
    options: '-x test -x integrationTest' // exclude both test and IT
  displayName: Generate AAR Lib
```